# Custom component as content in Ionic LoadingController

Tags: ionic-framework

I'd created custom component (ex. ) which contains animated image (css animation) + text (getting text from attribute, ex. ).

I'm using it as as spinner while loading some blocks of data, but I'd like to use it also as a loading controller. Ionic docs said that I should just use:

```
  let loading = this.loadingCtrl.create({
    spinner: 'hide',
    content: `<my-component></my-component>`
  });
  loading.present();
```

It should show a loading with my animated image (from component), but I see only empty square. Is it possible to use custom component as a content of loader?

Comment: any progress? I want to do something similar.

Comment: @Ali, I didn't done what I need, but I'd created a custom controller (for example name of this is CustomLoadingController), which has method named "create". Controller have same attributes as LoadingController (additionally attribute "animation" and some more, which I need) and in my "create" method I'm generating LoadingController based on my options and then return loadingcontroller.create(); It's not exactly what I want, but it's working.